# ¿Me sale a fecha atrasada cuando le doy un formato?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Lo que pasa es que estoy tratando de darle un formato a una fecha que tengo en `String`, pero cuando le doy el formato que quiero la fecha me sale atrasada, a continuación muestro código de lo que me esta sucediendo:

```
public class consala2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numero = dateCurrentFormater("2019-07-11");
        System.out.println(numero);
    }


    public static String dateCurrentFormater(String date) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date formatDate = null;
        try {
            formatDate = format.parse(date);
       } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd 'de' MMMM YYYY ");

        return dateFormat.format(formatDate);
    }
}
```

y esto es lo que me esta imprimiendo

```
sábado 11 de julio 0016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta clase a mi me funciona correctamente,

```
public class FechaFormato {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String numero = dateCurrentFormater("2019-07-12");

    System.out.println(numero);

}

private static String dateCurrentFormater(String date) {


    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date formatDate = null;

    try {
        formatDate = formatter.parse(date);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }

   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd 'de' MMMM YYYY");

   return dateFormat.format(formatDate);


}
```

}

El día de ayer lo cambié por el de hoy.

Comment: Gracias, copie y pegue y me funciono bien, voy a comparar que tengo malo en mi codigo

Answer (score 0):

Corrige la linea

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Por esta otra,

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
```

El resto lo dejas igual.

Comment: el nombre format por formatter es por costumbre, perdona!

Comment: Ya lo cambie pero me sigue saliendo la fecha mal asi :  (0016-07-11)

Comment: Te voy a pegar mi clase completa para que la veas